# Jmeter:Load Test Using Recorded Script

Tags: jmeter

I have a recorded script in J meter and now i want to test the recorded script with more number of virtual users.Is there anyway to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you must create a thread group and specify the number of conccurent user in `Thread Properties>Number of Thread(users)`
In your thread group, put your recorded script

You can find more details here
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf